# Datatable default ordering not applying

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have this code for jQuery Datatables, it works fine, everything is working as it should aside from the order function is not sorting the column on page load (or at all).

What am I doing wrong here? I've read Datatables documentation and this appears to be correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "url": "package.json",
            "dataSrc": "search_result",
            "order": [ 0, "desc" ]
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "num" },
            { "data": "domain_name",
              "render": function(data, type, row, meta)
              {
                if(type === 'display')
                {
                    data = '<a class="intel_link" href="http://www.' + data + '" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
                }

                return data;}
            },
            { "data": "query_time"},
            { "data": "create_date" },
            { "data": "update_date" },
            { "data": "expiry_date" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with sort attr, its written inside ajax block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "url": "package.json",
            "dataSrc": "search_result"
        },
        "order": [ 0, "desc" ]
        "columns": [
            { "data": "num" },
            { "data": "domain_name",
              "render": function(data, type, row, meta)
              {
                if(type === 'display')
                {
                    data = '<a class="intel_link" href="http://www.' + data + '" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
                }

                return data;}
            },
            { "data": "query_time"},
            { "data": "create_date" },
            { "data": "update_date" },
            { "data": "expiry_date" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

For more detail ref [Datable Order](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order)